# VS Code: install extensions system wide via CLI as root

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to install VS Code + some extensions ([Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) to be exact) on the PCs (CentOS) in our university lab. I installed the editor itself according to the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_rhel-fedora-and-centos-based-distributions), but I'm running into problems when I want to install extensions. I'm logging into the systems as root via ssh.

Running `sudo code --install-extension vscjava.vscode-java-pack --user-data-dir /some/dir` ([source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions)) runs successfully, and the extensions are available when VS Code runs as root. The problem is: When I start VS Code as another user, the extensions are *not* installed.

My questions are:

- What is stored in the `user-data-dir`? Does it contain the location of the `extensions-dir`? If yes, is it wise to share it across all users of the system?
- What is the recommended way to install extensions system wide for different users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also need to be able to install extensions systemwide, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this. The best solution I've found is to write a batch file that installs the extensions and then starts VS Code. I have users run that scr